# Adding function signatures to existing protocols in Swift

Tags: swift, cocoa, inheritance, swift-protocols

We have a big codebase with many `NSCollectionViews`, and we want to add a feature to control the `views` with the keyboard while changing the least amount of code possible.

To do that, we'd like to handle the keys in one file and simply fire the "Action Fired" events via a **delegate protocol**. Our `NSCollectionView` already implement the `NSCollectionViewDelegate protocol`, so we'd like to add the events directly to that protocol instead of doing it by inheritance.

Now, I know you can extend a protocol with the `extension` keyword that way:

```
extension NSCollectionViewDelegate {
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: NSCollectionView, didMoveLeft: Bool) {
        // Default implementation here
    }
}
```

The problem with this approach is that, since the signature hasn't been declared in the original protocol, the default implementation will always be called, even if a class implements its own.

So what would be the best way to truly extend the functions of a protocol so that all my existing `NSCollectionViews` would be able to implement their own behaviour without subclassing the `protocol`?

So far, I found the "best way" to do it would be to write the following:

```
extension NSCollectionView {
    override open func moveLeft(_ sender: Any?) {
        (delegate as? NSCollectionViewDelegateExtended)?.collectionView(self, didMoveLeft: true)
    }
}

protocol NSCollectionViewDelegateExtended : NSCollectionViewDelegate {
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: NSCollectionView, didMoveLeft: Bool)
}
```

And then implement `NSCollectionViewDelegateExtended` instead of `NSCollectionViewDelegate`:

```
extension CustomViewController: NSCollectionViewDelegateExtended {
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: NSCollectionView, didMoveLeft: Bool) {
        // Implementation here
    }
}
```

But that's not quite what I want. Is there a better way to seamlessly embed that new function in `NSCollectionViewDelegate`?

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to add the new delegate methods as `optional`. Keep in mind that in order to do this, you will have to open your protocol for `objective-C`. This can be done like below

```
@objc protocol MyProtocol {
    //older method 1
    //older method 2
    //...
    //older method X

    @objc optional func newMethod()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure this is true?

> The problem with this approach is that, since the signature hasn't
>   been declared in the original protocol, the default implementation
>   will always be called, even if a class implements its own.

I did a quick test, and the custom implementation of the extended protocol method got called.

```
protocol AProtocol: class {
    func baseMethod()
}

extension AProtocol {
    func extendenMethod() {
        print("Extended default implementation")
    }
}

class A: NSObject, AProtocol {
    func baseMethod() {
        print("Base")
    }
    func extendenMethod() {
        print("Extended custom implementation")
    }
}

let a = A()

a.baseMethod()
a.extendenMethod()
```

Results in:

```
Base
Extended custom implementation
```

Comment: Ah, I should have been more clear. If you call the method directly on the class it works fine, but if you call the method from the protocol and the class has no knowledge of the concrete type, it will call the default implementation, which is normal and by design.